# Placing & Positioning images using CSS?

Tags: html, css, slideshow, css-position

Edited this question entirely, not sure if it made sense previously.

Ok, I am having difficulty positioning some images on a website.  I am using the slidedeck jQuery slideshow, and in the third slide I want a portfolio of work, so just to display 6 images (2 rows of 3).

In the index.html the slides are set up as follows;

```
<div id="slidedeck_frame" class="skin-voyager"> 
<dl class="slidedeck">

<dt>ABOUT US</dt> 
<dd>About the company here</dd> 

<dt>OUR SERVICES</dt> 
<dd>Company services here</dd>

<dt>PORTFOLIO</dt> 
<dd>Images of completed work here</dd> 

<dt>Contact Us</dt> 
<dd>Contact form here</dd>

</dl>
</div>
```

Each of these slides is formatted in the CSS sheet with the following tag;

```
.slidedeck dd.slide_1
```

In the third slide, I need to be able to simply show rows of images using the CSS to position them.  I have tried a number of things but can't get it right.  In the index.html I have tried;

```
<dt>PORTFOLIO</dt> 
<dd><img src="images/myImage1.png" width="130" height="130" />
</dd>
```

But that obviously just display an image, with no ability to format it.

I have also tried;

```
<dt>PORTFOLIO</dt> 
<dd>
<div>
    <img id="image1" src="images/myImage1.png" width="130" height="130">
</div>
</dd>
```

and then using the following CSS to position;

```
img#image1 {
position: relative;
top: 20px;
left: 10px;
z-index: 5;
```

}

But the image just doesn't show up at all.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are styling with `dd.slide_1` but none of the `<dd>` elements have that class applied.

*Edit*

Given this html:

```
<dl class="slidedeck">
    <dt>PORTFOLIO</dt>
    <dd>
        <img src="images/myImage1.png" width="130" height="130" />
        <img src="images/myImage2.png" width="130" height="130" />
        <img src="images/myImage3.png" width="130" height="130" />
        <img src="images/myImage4.png" width="130" height="130" />
        <img src="images/myImage5.png" width="130" height="130" />
        <img src="images/myImage6.png" width="130" height="130" />
    </dd>
```

You should be able to style your images like this

```
.slidedeck dd img {
    /* add whatever styles you want */
}
```

If that isn't working try adding `!important` after your style values. If this works investigate what CSS (perhaps from jQuery plugins) is interfering with your styles. Try not to leave `!important` in if you can help it.

So for 2 rows of 3 images you would need this css

```
.slidedeck dd {
    width: 390px; /* 3x your image width */
    overflow: hidden; /* To contain floats */
}

.slidedeck dd img {
    float: left;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not entirely sure what you mean.  The <dd> elements are all in a <div id="slidedeck_frame"> and have a <dl class="slidedeck"> preceeding.

Comment: In your stylesheet what styles do you have for `.slidedeck dd.slide_1` ? Just going off the code you have posted you haven't applied the class `slide_1` to any `<dd>` elements which means whatever you intended to happen to `dd.slide_1` isn't going to happen.

Comment: In .slidedeck dd.slide_1 at the minute I just have standard CSS to format the text in there.  Which works fine, so it is being applied.

Comment: Thanks for the above answer.  It gets me a lot further than where I was.  It style the images with 5 on the first row then 1 on the second row. I will have a play around.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: That's odd that it is placing 5 on the first row and 1 on the second. Glad I could help you in the right direction though.

Comment: I have managed now to get my two rows of three.  However, it is placing them all right beside each other with what looks like maybe a couple of pixels space between.  Is it possible to pad the distance between the images so they are spaced out equally in the area?

Comment: Try this `.slidedeck dd img { padding:0; margin:5px; }` But bare in mind you will need to increase the width of the containing `<dd>` to be 3 x the image's width + 6 x 5px padding (5px for each side of the 3 images)

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, adding padding:0; margin:5px; and increasing the size of the <dd>.  Doesn't seem to make any difference to it.

Comment: Can't really help you much further I'm afraid without having a proper look at all your code. What I have suggested works perfectly in my fiddle so there must be something else affecting it. Good luck!

Comment: Yeah I can see your fiddle works perfectly. Thanks for that.  I have tried it, and it just does not change the way the images are placed.  Thanks for the help though, I will keep trying things :)